# How to strip everything from a row value except the first instance of an int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a row value as such:

```
Blow Balloons 5 Yes 4
3 Shirt No 
Goodbye Something 2 1
```

Then I just want it to be:

```
5
3
2
```

So the first instance of an int. How can I do that? I can't use a regex because there's no pattern for when the number first appears.

Comment: ``df["header"].str.extract(r"(\d)")``?

Comment: show us your code thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. It actually use regex :

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['Blow Balloons 5 Yes 4', 
        '3 Shirt No', 
        'Goodbye Something 2 1']
data = pd.Series(data)
data = data.str.replace(r'\D+', ' ').str.split()
data = data.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: For some reason I get an index out of range with that lambda - I print out data and it looks as it's intended with the column being a list of 1 element? I had to do ''.join(x) as the lambda

Comment: This is because you have some rows without int. You can use an if statement inside the lambda function like so :
data.apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else '')

Comment: be careful with using ''.join(x) if you have numbers greater than 9. It will keep only the first character. If you only have numbers between 0 and 9, you can use this solution instead: data.str.replace(r'\D+', '').str[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

list = ['Blow Balloons 5 Yes 4', 
    '3 Shirt No', 
    'Goodbye Something 2 1']

regex = re.compile("(\d){1}")

for str in list:
    data = regex.search(str).group()
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
5
3
2
```